# Email templates stripped of style tags

Tags: civimail, message-templates, templates

Style tags cannot be saved in message templates and have in fact been stripped from current templates. We use a number of templates based on the Single Column Responsive Sample Template. In the last month, all the templates that used to contain a style tag that made the templates responsive have been stripped from the templates, including the sample template. Any attempts to re-add the style tag (or any style tag at all) seem to save fine, but on viewing do not have the style tag. Other changes are saved properly. I think this is since upgrading to 4.6.22, but am not sure of this.

Style tags can still be saved in CiviMail directly, just not in the templates.

CiviCRM 4.6.22 & Drupal 7.50

Comment: I don't have a good answer, as this seems to be working fine for us in civiCRM 4.6.4 - but it's probably relevant to post which WYSIWYG Editor you're using plus it's version, given the nature of the issue. I did start seeing some certain tags getting stripped and jammed into <style> in unexpected ways when we upgraded to a new version of the full ckEditor.

Comment: We are using CKEditor.

Comment: This was incorrect, we use CKEditor for CiviMail, but TinyMCE for template editing.

Answer (score 2):

Changing from TinyMCE for template editing to CKEditor solved this problem. Verified that switching back to TinyMCE causes style tags to be stripped.