# CiviMail template format in HTML not saving

Tags: civimail, message-templates

My issue is related to [this post by @John,](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4528/how-can-i-use-html-head-body-tags-in-a-mailing) I think.

I recently upgraded from 4.6.XX to 4.7.14.  I had beautiful formatted email templates that I use regularly.  I am trying to use my template now in 4.7.14, and it strips all the HTML formatting, such as background color, font type, font color, etc. from the email.  When I try to save it, all the formatting disappears.

I've set Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Display Preferences > Configure CKEditor > CiviMail tab > Advanced options > Set fullPage = true as an option, per @Coleman.  But that has not fixed my issue.

What am I missing?

Comment: This question: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15330/email-templates-stripped-of-style-tags makes me think that maybe you're using TinyMCE and not CKEditor for template editing.  Can you check **Administer » Customize Data and Screens » Display Preferences" and update your question to confirm the WYSIWYG editor that's set?

Comment: I saw that thread, thanks.  When I go to Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Display Preferences, I have two WYSIWYG editor options to choose from: CKEditor and Textarea.  I am using CKEditor.

Comment: Update, I think that perhaps this has to do with the functionalities that are enabled in my CKEditor.  When I use the UI, I don't see the Advanced tab for Table Properties. So evidently, I don't have all the functionalities enabled.  I didn't customize CKEditor when I installed it, and it was working fine before I upgraded CiviCRM to 4.7...

Comment: And I am in Joomla.

Comment: We had the same problem and solved this. Our solution is here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17355/is-this-a-bug-civicrm-files-variable/17470#17470