# 4.7.15 breaks civimail styles and templates (fullPage doesn't help)

Tags: civimail, drupal, ckeditor

Since upgrading to Civi 4.7.15 CKEditor is stripping out the email headers and style tags on three Drupal 7 sites. One site is hosted on a shared/multi-site and the other two on AegirVPS.

This problem may have first surfaced in 4.7.14. ([See this similar post about Joomla](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16536/civimail-template-format-in-html-not-saving))

I have set both config.fullPage and config.allowedContent to true using the configurator, and the changes are reflected in the config files in files/civicrm/persist (crm-ckeditor-civimail.js and crm-ckeditor-default.js).

The changes aren't reflecting in the editor (I also removed some buttons which also still appear in the editor).

I have cleared Drupal, Civi and browser caches, deactivated JS aggregation, and tested on Chrome and Firefox without joy.

When I click the source button the full email flashes briefly but then strips out the tags.

Is there something I'm missing? / Can anyone suggest another solution? @Coleman?